# Can't use custom seperator in opencsv

Tags: java, opencsv, import-from-csv

I need to get the values from my csv file and for this I need to set the seperator to ';' and the values are in '"'.

If I try it like this:

```
    final CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file"), ';', '"', 1);

    String[] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        if (nextLine != null) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nextLine));
        }
    }
```

The compiler gives me this error
`The constructor CSVReader(FileReader, char, char) is undefined`

If I use it without the ';', '"', 1. I get everything that is in my file but it has a strange output.

**My file got 10000 values like:**

`"00026";"01402118";"Zeitsoldat/in"`
`"00027";"11101118";"Ackerarbeiter/in"`

and the output looks like:
`[00026";"01402118";"Zeitsoldat/in]`
`[00027";"11101118";"Ackerarbeiter/in]`

Comment: Can you add some lines of your input `CSV` file to your question?

Comment: they are the nearly the same as in the question from 1 - 10000. First line is ID; ID2, NAME. 
ID is allways one more, ID2 is differernt each time and Name could be the same bus it is allways the same structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that your code works for older versions of `opencsv`. I tested your code with `3.3` and it works perfectly. I then looked into what is different in a newer version (`5.5.2`). I noticed that the creation of the `CSVReader` differs a lot. Following code works for the new version:

```java
CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(';').withQuoteChar('"').build();
CSVReader reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new FileReader("input_files/input.csv"))
        .withSkipLines(1)
        .withCSVParser(parser)
        .build();

String[] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    if (nextLine != null) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nextLine));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[00026, 01402118, Zeitsoldat/in]
[00027, 11101118, Ackerarbeiter/in]
```

So, in order to solve your problem you have to find the right code for your version. If you use the newest version, you can simply copy above code.